# positive lookahead works whereas negative lookbehind doesn't

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind, positive-lookahead

Let's assume I want to match a sentence like :

> Home is now behind you, the world is ahead!

this way:

```
^.*(?<=(H|h)ome).*(w|W)orld.*(\.|!)$
```

This seems to work fine. ([see on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6WLr8A/1))

Now let's assume I'd like to exclude sentences in which the words 'home' and 'world' come in the reverse order:

> World is now behind you, the home is ahead!

I tried this ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cqY47S/1)):

```
^.*(?<!(w|W)orld).*(H|h)ome.*(\.|!)$
```

This one doesn't work... :-(

Could anyone please explain how to achieve it with negative lookbehinds or by another mean ?...

Comment: In my experience, negative lookbehind hardly ever works. But, as shown in Tim's answer, it can usefully be replaced by negative lookahead.

Comment: What is your regex flavor ?

Comment: Keep in mind that whatever the pattern you write, the regex engine always tries to make it succeed.

Comment: Thx @Casimir_and_Hippolyte, following your comment I made further tests and here's what I understood : in this case `.*(H|h)ome` is not preceded by _anything_, as  `.*(H|h)ome` can indeed match the _whole_ string.

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase your requirement as:

```regex
^(?i)(?!.*\bworld\b.*\bhome\b).*\bhome\b.*\bworld\b.*$
```

### Demo

The negative lookahead at the start of the pattern asserta that `world` is not followed by `home` in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Positive and negative lookahead/lookbehind depend on your regex processor. Not all processors support this feature.

If I remember correctly, negative lookbehind is seldom implemented.

I have tried your regex at https://regexr.com and it seems to work correctly.

Comment: I've tried it too (didn't know this site), negative lookbehind doesn't work. That' a pity negative lookbehinds don't work, but, ok I'll use a workaround, as Tim explains :-)